# Angular ClickEvent can only bind to a full document instead of a kendo tree view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

So I have a Kendo UI Treeview and I'm trying to add a double clicker using the following code:

```
let treeview_mouse_event = fromEvent(document.getElementById('kendo-treeview'), 'dblclick').subscribe((mEv: MouseEvent) => {
      if(document.getElementById('kendo-treeview').click!=null)
      {
        console.log(mEv.timeStamp);
      }
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
 getElementById(...) is null
```

Any clue why that is happening? If I remove the getElementById part then the binding to the whole document works, but that's not what I want, because I only want to bind to the tree view elements.